# Como puedo estilar un selector css que no es pariente cuando un input esta checkeado? solamente con css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, scss

Quiero hacer un dark-mode para mi página, utilizando solamente CSS. Para ello, creé un input type checkbox que me permite hacer el switch entre un label de "modo oscuro" y otro label "modo claro". Para esto use input:checkbox + .clasedelhermano{} y funcionó, pero ahora, cuando quiero editar un selector que no esta  dentro de su rama, no se como llegar a este. En este caso, me gustaría editar el div con clase "purple-rectangle" utilizando el checkbox de id "dark-mode".

```
 <div class="purple-rectangle"></div>
    <header class="header">
        <img class="logo" src="GIFOS_UI+Kit_Desktop+y+Mobile/GIFOS-UI-Desktop+Mobile-Update/assets/logo-mobile.svg" alt="logo">
        <div class="menu-hamb">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <img class="burguer hamb" src="GIFOS_UI+Kit_Desktop+y+Mobile/GIFOS-UI-Desktop+Mobile-Update/assets/burger.svg" alt="burguer">
            <img class="close hamb" src="GIFOS_UI+Kit_Desktop+y+Mobile/GIFOS-UI-Desktop+Mobile-Update/assets/close.svg" alt="close">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <ul class="navlist">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="dark-mode">
                    <li class="navitem day" id="day">Modo Nocturno</li>
                    <li class="navitem night" id="night">Modo Diurno</li>
                    <li class="navitem">Favoritos</li>
                    <li class="navitem">Mis Gifos</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <img id="create-gif" class="create-gif" src="GIFOS_UI+Kit_Desktop+y+Mobile/GIFOS-UI-Desktop+Mobile-Update/assets/button-crear-gifo.svg" alt="">
    </header>
```

```
.navlist input:checked ~ .day {
    display: none;
}
.navlist #dark-mode:not(:checked) ~ .night{
    display: none;
}

// esta es la linea que nose como hacer
 #dark-mode:checked +.purple-rectangle{
   background-color: $primary-color-dark;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor la duda por favor?

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo estilar el div con clase "purple-rectangle", cuando el input con id "dark-mode"  está checkeado? (en caso que no esté checkeado que mantenga el estilo original)

Comment: no puedes. En css no hay un selector para hacer referencia al elemento padre y cambiar sus estilos. Necesitarás usar javascript o poner `<input type="checkbox" id="dark-mode"/>` como hermano del elemento `.purple-rectangle`